# React Native Incompatible With Google VR SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

I'm having a trouble with React Native when I try to add the [Google VR SDK](https://developers.google.com/vr/ios/get-started) ('GVRSDK') as a Podfile dependency, and it's quite easy to replicate.

Steps:

1. Create a new blank React Native project. Run it with `react-native run-ios` to ensure it worked.
2. `cd ios`
3. `pod init`
4. Add `pod 'GVRSDK'` to Podfile, execute `pod update`
5. `cd ..`
6. `react-native run-ios`

The project crashed with the following error:

```
duplicate symbol __ZN3fLI9FLAGS_novE in:
/foo/ios/Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries/libGVRSDK.a(vlog_is_on.o)
/foo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(vlog_is_on.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN3fLI7FLAGS_vE in:
/foo/ios/Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries/libGVRSDK.a(vlog_is_on.o)
/foo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(vlog_is_on.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN6google13RemoveLogSinkEPNS_7LogSinkE in:
/foo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(logging.o)
/foo/ios/Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries/libGVRSDK.a(logging.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN6google10AddLogSinkEPNS_7LogSinkE in:
/foo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(logging.o)
    /foo/ios/Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries/libGVRSDK.a(logging.o)
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)



** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:

Ld build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/foo.app/foo normal x86_64
(1 failure)
```

Comment: Downgrading to React Native 0.44.1 (from 0.45.1) seems to fix this.

Comment: Same for me. Downgrading (from 0.45.1 to 0.44.3) fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve it by removing the duplicated symbol in libGVRSDK.a.
The **lipo** and **ar** commands are used to disassemble the library file in the several architectures and rearchive them into another file.

I made the shell script as follows:

pod_post_install.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ./Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries/
lipo -info libGVRSDK.a

# Divide to each platform
lipo -thin armv7 libGVRSDK.a -output libGVRSDK_armv7
lipo -thin i386 libGVRSDK.a -output libGVRSDK_i386
lipo -thin x86_64 libGVRSDK.a -output libGVRSDK_x86_64
lipo -thin arm64 libGVRSDK.a -output libGVRSDK_arm64

# Delete duplicate file
chmod 777 libGVRSDK_armv7
chmod 777 libGVRSDK_i386
chmod 777 libGVRSDK_x86_64
chmod 777 libGVRSDK_arm64

ar -dv libGVRSDK_armv7 vlog_is_on.o
ar -dv libGVRSDK_i386 vlog_is_on.o
ar -dv libGVRSDK_x86_64 vlog_is_on.o
ar -dv libGVRSDK_arm64 vlog_is_on.o

# rm libGVRSDK.a
lipo -create libGVRSDK_armv7 libGVRSDK_i386 libGVRSDK_x86_64 libGVRSDK_arm64 -output libGVRSDK.a

# Delete media
rm libGVRSDK_armv7
rm libGVRSDK_i386
rm libGVRSDK_x86_64
rm libGVRSDK_arm64

cd ../../../
```

It can be more useful if this script is invoked when every pod install is run.

Podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
    system(". ./pod_post_install.sh")
end
```

I believe it helps.